# If $x\geq -1$, prove that $(x+1)^3=x$ has no solutions

Tags: polynomials

$$(x+1)^3=x$$
$$x^3+1+2x+3x^2=0$$

Differentiating the eqn., $3x^2+6x+2=0$. This is zero at $(-6 + \sqrt{6})/6$ or $(-6 -\sqrt{6})/6$

It will give a local minima at $(-6 + \sqrt{24})/6$ and a local maxima at $(-6 -\sqrt{24})/6$. Both these numbers are very close to $-1$ so this means a root can't exist near $x=-1$ but it doesn't tell us anything else about what will happen at larger values of x How can I proceed further?

Comment: The roots of $3 x^2 + 6 x + 2$ are $-1 \pm 1/\sqrt{3}$ which is different than what you wrote. Luckily, as other answers have pointed out, that is not necessary to solve the problem. Another way of writing it would be $(-6 \pm \sqrt{12})/6$.

Comment: Sunaina, my answer was incorrect or at least incomplete. There are still sign changes for $x\in(-1,0)$

Comment: It has been resolved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiating isn't especially relevant here. An immediate way to solve this is to see that for $x\ge-1$, $(x+1)^3\gt x\ge0$, and that leaves the polynomial $x^3+3x^2+2x+1=0$ with zero sign changes - by [Descarte's rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), this proves there are no real roots with $x\ge-1$.

EDIT:

I have just realised that this answer is in fact not correct. For $x\in(-1,0)$ there *are* sign changes!

A resolution to this is the following observation:

$x\in(-1,0)\implies (x+1)^3\ge0.$ However, $x\lt0$, so the equality cannot hold.

Answer (score 5):

If $x \geq -1$ then $x+1 \geq 0$.  When you cube this, it will thus be positive.  This can only equal $x$ again if $x > 0$.  But if $x > 0$, it is easy to see that $(x+1)^3 =x$ is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The given equation is

$x(x+1)(x+2)=-1$

Now $x\geq -1$

If $x\geq 0$, then RHS cannot be equal to LHS as positive or zero is never equal to negative.

If $x =-1$ , then LHS=0 but RHS is not, therefore equality doesn't holds

Now we are left to check for $x\in (-1,0)$. For that we  use our original equation

$(x+1)^3=x$. If $x\in (-1,0)$, then $x+1\in (0,1)$ and therefore $(x+1)^3 >0$

But then LHS becomes positive and RHS remains negative, therefore again equality doesn't holds

Hence proved